# Hiranyagarbha Suktam and translation in English

Tags: scripture, vedas, translation-request

What is Hiranyagarbha Suktam? What is the translation in English?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Hirayagarbha Sukta is a hymn from the Rig Veda{RV 10:121}. It praises the Creator, his Creations and his treasures.

### Sanskrit Verse

### हिरण्यगर्भः समवर्तताग्रे भूतस्य जातः पतिरेकासीत । स दाधार पृथ्वीं ध्यामुतेमां कस्मै देवायहविषा विधेम ॥

hiraṇyagarbhaḥ samavartatāgre bhūtasya jātaḥ patirekāsīta |
sa dādhāra pṛthvīṃ dhyāmutemāṃ kasmai devāyahaviṣā vidhema ||

### य आत्मदा बलदा यस्य विश्व उपासते प्रशिषं यस्यदेवाः । यस्य छायामृतं यस्य मर्त्युः कस्मै देवायहविषा विधेम ॥

ya ātmadā baladā yasya viśva upāsate praśiṣaṃ yasyadevāḥ |
yasya chāyāmṛtaṃ yasya martyuḥ kasmai devāyahaviṣā vidhema ||

### यः प्राणतो निमिषतो महित्वैक इद्राजा जगतो बभूव । य ईशे अस्य द्विपदश्चतुष्पदः कस्मै देवाय हविषाविधेम ॥

yaḥ prāṇato nimiṣato mahitvaika idrājā jagato babhūva |
ya īśe asya dvipadaścatuṣpadaḥ kasmai devāya haviṣāvidhema ||

### यस्येमे हिमवन्तो महित्वा यस्य समुद्रं रसया सहाहुः । यस्येमाः परदिशो यस्य बाहू कस्मै देवाय हविषाविधेम ॥

yasyeme himavanto mahitvā yasya samudraṃ rasayā sahāhuḥ |
yasyemāḥ paradiśo yasya bāhū kasmai devāya haviṣāvidhema ||

### येन दयौरुग्रा पर्थिवी च दर्ळ्हा येन सव सतभितं येननाकः । यो अन्तरिक्षे रजसो विमानः कस्मै देवायहविषा विधेम ॥

yena dayaurugrā parthivī ca darḻhā yena sava satabhitaṃ yenanākaḥ |
yo antarikṣe rajaso vimānaḥ kasmai devāyahaviṣā vidhema ||

### यं करन्दसी अवसा तस्तभाने अभ्यैक्षेतां मनसारेजमाने । यत्राधि सूर उदितो विभाति कस्मै देवायहविषा विधेम ॥

yaṃ karandasī avasā tastabhāne abhyaikṣetāṃ manasārejamāne |
yatrādhi sūra udito vibhāti kasmai devāyahaviṣā vidhema ||

### आपो ह यद बर्हतीर्विश्वमायन गर्भं दधानाजनयन्तीरग्निम । ततो देवानां समवर्ततासुरेकःकस्मै देवाय हविषा विधेम ॥

āpo ha yada barhatīrviśvamāyana garbhaṃ dadhānājanayantīragnima |
tato devānāṃ samavartatāsurekaḥkasmai devāya haviṣā vidhema ||

### यश्चिदापो महिना पर्यपश्यद दक्षं दधानाजनयन्तीर्यज्ञम । यो देवेष्वधि देव एक आसीत कस्मैदेवाय हविषा विधेम ॥

yaścidāpo mahinā paryapaśyada dakṣaṃ dadhānājanayantīryajñama |
yo deveṣvadhi deva eka āsīta kasmaidevāya haviṣā vidhema ||

### मा नो हिंसीज्जनिता यः पर्थिव्या यो वा दिवंसत्यधर्मा जजान । यश्चापश्चन्द्रा बर्हतीर्जजानकस्मै देवाय हविषा विधेम ॥

mā no hiṃsījjanitā yaḥ parthivyā yo vā divaṃsatyadharmā jajāna |
yaścāpaścandrā barhatīrjajānakasmai devāya haviṣā vidhema ||

### परजापते न तवदेतान्यन्यो विश्वा जातानि परि ताबभूव । यत्कामास्ते जुहुमस्तन नो अस्तु वयं सयाम पतयोरयीणाम ॥

parajāpate na tavadetānyanyo viśvā jātāni pari tābabhūva |
yatkāmāste juhumastana no astu vayaṃ sayāma patayorayīṇ

### Translation of Hiranyagarbha Sukta in English

{1}In the beginning was the Divinity in his splendour, manifested as the sole Lord of land, skies, water, space and that beneath and He upheld the earth and the heavens.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?

{2}It is He who bestows soul-force and vigor, whose guidance all men invoke, the Devas invoke-whose shadow is immortal life and death.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?

{3}It is He who by His greatness became the One King of the breathing and the seeing, who is the Lord of man and bird and beast.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?

{4}It is He through whose glory the snow-clad mountains rose, and the ocean spread with the river, they say. His arms are the quarters of the sky.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings ?

{5}It is He through whom the heaven is strong and the earth firm, who has steadied the light and the sky's vault, and measured out the sphere of clouds in the mid-region.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offering?

{6}It is He to whom heaven and earth, placed in the light by his grace, look up, radiant with the mind while over them the sun, rising, brightly shines.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?

{7}When the mighty waters came, carrying the universal germ, producing the flame of life, then dwelt there in harmony the One Spirit of the Devas.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?

{8}It is He who in his might surveyed the waters, conferring skill and creating worship - He, the God of gods, the One and only One.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?

{9}Father of the world - may He not destroy us who with Truth as his Law made the heavens and produced waters, vast and beautiful.
Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?

{10}Lord of creation! No one other than thee pervades all these that have come into being.
May that be ours, for which our prayers rise, may we be masters of many treasures!--

### (RV 10:121) Ralph T. H. Griffith

1. HIRANYAGARBHA was present at the beginning ; when born, he was the sole lord of created beings; he upheld this earth and heaven,
   -let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
2. (To him) who is the giver of soul, the giver of strength, Whose commands all (beings), even the gods obey, Whose shadow is immortality, whose (shadow) is death,
   -let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
3. (To him) who, by his greatness, has verily become the sole king of the breathing and seeing world, who rules over this aggregate of two-footed and four-footed beings,-
   let us offer Worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
4. Through whose greatness these snow-clad (moun- tains exist), whose property men call the ocean with the rivers, whose are these quarters of space, whose are the two arms,
   --let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
5. By whom the sky was made profound and the earth solid, by Whom heaven and the solar sphere were fixed, who was the measure of the water in the firmament,-
   let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
6. Whom heaven and earth established by his pro- tection, and, shining brightly, regarded with their mind, in whom the risen sun shines forth,
   -let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
7. When the vast waters overspread the universe containing the germ and giving birth to AGNI, then was produced the one breath of the gods,
   -let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
8. He who by his might beheld the waters all around containing the creative power and giving birth to sacrifice, he who among the gods was the one supreme god,-
   let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
9. May he do us no harm who is the parent of the-earth, or who the unerring support (of the world) begat the heaven, and who generated the vast and delightful waters,
   -let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
10. No other than thou, PRAJAPATI, hast given existence to all these beings ; may that object of our desires for which we sacrifice to thee be ours, may we be the possessors of riches.

[H. H. Wilson]

---

Reference- [Rig Veda{RV 10:121}Hirayagarbha Sukta](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10121.htm)

Answer (score 5):

> **Sanskrit Verse**
>
> **हिरण्यगर्भः समवर्तताग्रे भूतस्य जातः पतिरेकासीत ।**
>
> **स दाधार पृथ्वीं ध्यामुतेमां कस्मै देवायहविषा विधेम ॥**
>
> hiraṇyagarbhaḥ samavartatāgre bhūtasya jātaḥ patirekāsīta |
>
> sa dādhāra pṛthvīṃ dhyāmutemāṃ kasmai devāyahaviṣā vidhema ||
>
> **य आत्मदा बलदा यस्य विश्व उपासते प्रशिषं यस्यदेवाः ।**
>
> **यस्य छायामृतं यस्य मर्त्युः कस्मै देवायहविषा विधेम ॥**
>
> ya ātmadā baladā yasya viśva upāsate praśiṣaṃ yasyadevāḥ |
>
> yasya chāyāmṛtaṃ yasya martyuḥ kasmai devāyahaviṣā vidhema ||
>
> **यः प्राणतो निमिषतो महित्वैक इद्राजा जगतो बभूव ।**
>
> **य ईशे अस्य द्विपदश्चतुष्पदः कस्मै देवाय हविषाविधेम ॥**
>
> yaḥ prāṇato nimiṣato mahitvaika idrājā jagato babhūva |
>
> ya īśe asya dvipadaścatuṣpadaḥ kasmai devāya haviṣāvidhema ||
>
> **यस्येमे हिमवन्तो महित्वा यस्य समुद्रं रसया सहाहुः ।**
>
> **यस्येमाः परदिशो यस्य बाहू कस्मै देवाय हविषाविधेम ॥**
>
> yasyeme himavanto mahitvā yasya samudraṃ rasayā sahāhuḥ |
>
> yasyemāḥ paradiśo yasya bāhū kasmai devāya haviṣāvidhema ||
>
> **येन दयौरुग्रा पर्थिवी च दर्ळ्हा येन सव सतभितं येननाकः ।**
>
> **यो अन्तरिक्षे रजसो विमानः कस्मै देवायहविषा विधेम ॥**
>
> yena dayaurugrā parthivī ca darḻhā yena sava satabhitaṃ yenanākaḥ |
>
> yo antarikṣe rajaso vimānaḥ kasmai devāyahaviṣā vidhema ||
>
> **यं करन्दसी अवसा तस्तभाने अभ्यैक्षेतां मनसारेजमाने ।**
>
> **यत्राधि सूर उदितो विभाति कस्मै देवायहविषा विधेम ॥**
>
> yaṃ karandasī avasā tastabhāne abhyaikṣetāṃ manasārejamāne |
>
> yatrādhi sūra udito vibhāti kasmai devāyahaviṣā vidhema ||
>
> **आपो ह यद बर्हतीर्विश्वमायन गर्भं दधानाजनयन्तीरग्निम ।**
>
> **ततो देवानां समवर्ततासुरेकःकस्मै देवाय हविषा विधेम ॥**
>
> āpo ha yada barhatīrviśvamāyana garbhaṃ dadhānājanayantīragnima |
>
> tato devānāṃ samavartatāsurekaḥkasmai devāya haviṣā vidhema ||
>
> **यश्चिदापो महिना पर्यपश्यद दक्षं दधानाजनयन्तीर्यज्ञम ।**
>
> **यो देवेष्वधि देव एक आसीत कस्मैदेवाय हविषा विधेम ॥**
>
> yaścidāpo mahinā paryapaśyada dakṣaṃ dadhānājanayantīryajñama |
>
> yo deveṣvadhi deva eka āsīta kasmaidevāya haviṣā vidhema ||
>
> **मा नो हिंसीज्जनिता यः पर्थिव्या यो वा दिवंसत्यधर्मा जजान ।**
>
> **यश्चापश्चन्द्रा बर्हतीर्जजानकस्मै देवाय हविषा विधेम ॥**
>
> mā no hiṃsījjanitā yaḥ parthivyā yo vā divaṃsatyadharmā jajāna |
>
> yaścāpaścandrā barhatīrjajānakasmai devāya haviṣā vidhema ||
>
> **परजापते न तवदेतान्यन्यो विश्वा जातानि परि ताबभूव ।**
>
> **यत्कामास्ते जुहुमस्तन नो अस्तु वयं सयाम पतयोरयीणाम ॥**
>
> parajāpate na tavadetānyanyo viśvā jātāni pari tābabhūva |
>
> yatkāmāste juhumastana no astu vayaṃ sayāma patayorayīṇāma ||
>
> **Translation in English**
>
> In the beginning was the Divinity in his [splendour](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/splendour), manifested as
>   the sole Lord of land, skies, water, space and that beneath and He
>   upheld the earth and the heavens. Who is the deity we shall worship
>   with our offerings?
>
> It is that who bestows soul-force and vigor, whose guidance all men
>   invoke, the Devas invoke whose shadow is immortal life and death. Who
>   is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?
>
> It is that who by His greatness became the One King of the breathing
>   and the seeing, who is the Lord of man and bird and beast. Who is the
>   deity we shall worship with our offerings?
>
> It is that through whose glory the snow-clad mountains rose, and the
>   ocean spread with the river, they say. His arms are the quarters of
>   the sky. Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings ?
>
> It is that through whom the heaven is strong and the earth firm, who
>   has steadied the light and the sky's vault, and measured out the
>   sphere of clouds in the mid-region. Who is the deity we shall worship
>   with our offering?
>
> It is that to whom heaven and earth, placed in the light by his grace,
>   look up, radiant with the mind while over them the sun, rising,
>   brightly shines. Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?
>
> When the mighty waters came, carrying the universal germ, producing
>   the flame of life, then dwelt there in harmony the One Spirit of the
>   Devas. Who is the deity we shall worship with our offerings?
>
> It is that who in its might surveyed the waters, conferring skill and
>   creating worship - That, the God of gods, the One and only One. Who is
>   the deity we shall worship with our offerings?
>
> Mother of the world - may that not destroy us who with Truth as his
>   Law made the heavens and produced waters, vast and beautiful. Who is
>   the deity we shall worship with our offerings?
>
> Lord of creation! No one other than thee pervades all these that have
>   come into being.
>
> May that be ours, for which our prayers rise, may we be masters of
>   many treasures!
>
> -- ([RV 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandala_10):121) [Ralph T. H. Griffith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_T._H._Griffith)
>
> 1. HIRANYAGARBHA was present at the beginning ; when born, he was the sole lord of created beings; he upheld this earth and heaven, -let us
>      offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
> 2. (To him) who is the giver of soul, the giver of strength, Whose commands all (beings), even the gods obey, Whose shadow is
>      immortality, whose (shadow) is death, -let us offer worship with an
>      oblation to the divine KA.
> 3. (To him) who, by his greatness, has verily become the sole king of the breathing and seeing world, who rules over this aggregate of
>      two-footed and four-footed beings,- let us offer Worship with an
>      oblation to the divine KA.
> 4. Through whose greatness these snow-clad (moun- tains exist), whose property men call the ocean with the rivers, whose are these quarters
>      of space, whose are the two arms, -let us offer worship with an
>      oblation to the divine KA.
> 5. By whom the sky was made profound and the earth solid, by Whom heaven and the solar sphere were fixed, who was the measure of the
>      water in the firmament,- let us offer worship with an oblation to the
>      divine KA.
> 6. Whom heaven and earth established by his pro- tection, and, shining brightly, regarded with their mind, in whom the risen sun shines
>      forth, -let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
> 7. When the vast waters overspread the universe containing the germ and giving birth to AGNI, then was produced the one breath of the
>      gods, -let us offer worship with an oblation to the divine KA.
> 8. He who by his might beheld the waters all around containing the creative power and giving birth to sacrifice, he who among the gods
>      was the one supreme god,-let us offer worship with an oblation to the
>      divine KA.
> 9. May he do us no harm who is the parent of the -earth, or who the unerring support (of the world) begat the heaven, and who generated
>      the vast and delightful waters,- let us offer worship with an oblation
>      to the divine KA.
> 10. No other than thou, PRAJAPATI, hast given existence to all these beings ; may that object of our desires for which we sacrifice to thee
>       be ours, may we be the possessors of riches.

Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiranyagarbha)