# How exactly does creation happen for Dwaithis?

Tags: vaishnavism, vedanta, dvaita

As Dwaitha professes athyanthika bheda between Jada, Jeeva and Ishwara. How is creation described?

What are the origin of Jeeva and Jada, if they have one, and what are their qualities according to Dvaitha.

What are the exact powers of Ishwara?

Comment: God is not material cause of the creation, all the materials where there before will exist forever along with ishawara and lakshmi.. jada and jeeva are not one

Comment: I agree that, I'm asking what is the process of creation according to dwaitha?

Comment: OK so Jada and Jeevas were not created by Ishwara? So how did the universe come to existence according to dvaitha, what is the theory. Or according to dvaitha did Ishwara create the universe, in what way did he create as Jada was already there?

Comment: yes by any chance you want to learn vedanta. than universe is created from 24 or 25 or 26 or  27  or 28 tattvas you need learn

Comment: Alright, but I am more interested in how Ishwara influenced the creation. What was the role of Ishwara in creation?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/hiranyagarbha-suktam-and-translation-in-english check this

Comment: The Sukta is highly poetic and abstract. Moreover its in Vedas. That means it is interpreted by all the three schools in their own way. That is I am asking specifically how does Dwaitha interpret it? There it says Lord of Creation. What do you mean by creation? as the Jada is already present. That's what I was interested in.

Comment: everything is present as atoms, subatoms god gave them form by creating various tattva abhimani devatha.. and assigned them the task, first he came from golden egg as hiranyagarbha and took four forms vasudeva, sankrshna, annirudha and pradhymna.. Lakshmi was there already as Abhimani devatha for prakuthi that is what is atoms and subatoms.. these four forms created all the 24 tattva required for creation.. Now you got 28 right.. this is one count. 24 is the basis tattva for universe..

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34866/are-there-verses-from-scriptures-which-list-24-tattvas-according-to-sankhya-dars

Comment: So basically according to Dwaitha, Ishwara rearranges the matter already present right. He does not "create" matter.

Comment: not re arrange its enabling.. 24  tattvas see in material parlns potter needs clay to create pot, now clay is prakurthi that is there already and pot is brahmanda that is going to be created.. after creating the pot here lies the magic he goes inside them and prevades the whole universe but in real world potter doesnt not become pot. here jiva is insentient before brahman sits into them.. inside every jiva paramatma should be there..

Comment: Beautiful analogy, you can write an answer, it will be helpful for everyone