# What is the Dvaitha world view?

Tags: vedanta, dvaita

I need some clarification about the ontological claims of Dvaitha Vedanta.

1. Who created Jada and Jeevatma, did Ishwara create these or were they always existing? i.e anadhi?
2. Did Vishnu create the Vedas, or Vedas were only revealed by him, but existed eternally and were not created by Vishnu?
3. Can Ishwara (Vishnu) change Jada to Jeevatma? If yes then it's not Athyanthika bheda, if no, Ishwara is not omnipotent. In that he can't do anything everything.

Please give appropriate citations.

Comment: 1. jaDa and jIva are beginningless. They are not created by Ishwara, but they are completely dependent on Ishwara. 2. Vedas existed eternally. They are apaurusheya or unauthored. 3. Ishwara can change jaDa to jIva. He has all powers, so he is omnipotent. **But he does not do such things in practice, even though he can.** So the bheda between jIva and jaDa is eternal.

Comment: @LazyLubber please write it as an answer of possible with some references.

Comment: 2. For the sake of clarity. When you say unauthored, you mean even God didn't author it right?

Comment: Yes, even God did not author them.

Comment: 3. I think there is 2 kinds of omnipotence. One that God can do all things which are possible. 3. God can do anything and everything. I don't think the second kind of omnipotence is possible. Because can God create new Jeevatma from void? Can God merge two Jeevatmas? Can God merge a Jeevatma intojimself? I think the answer is no. Just as God cannot create Vedas. He can't do these fundamental stuff.

Comment: Sorry, cant write as an answer. My dvaita references are currently inaccessible to me. One thing though - that resolution of omnipotence issue came from discussion with a few well-read dvaitins long back.

Comment: God can do every thing that is logically meaningful. For example, a square circle is logically meaningless. So, asking whether God can create a square circle is meaningless. Yes, God can create jIva from nothing. Merging jIvas is something that may be logically meaningless. Yes, God can create vedas.

Comment: apaurusheya - Apurushya doesnt mean unauthored. Wrong understanding. Its not created by man. Purusha also means man. Vedas is breath of Ishwara!

Comment: @akshays but purusha also means God, eg purushasuktha. I don't know this but Lazy lubber was saying it was not created by Ishwara. So I don't know Dvaitha opinion. They say it was involuntary breath. So it was involuntary. According to Advaitha, Vedas were not created by Ishwara. As far as I know

Comment: @LazyLubber Thanks. The problem is if God creates Jiva from nothing, then God can also destroy the Jiva. This is danger to nithyathva of Atma. Yes that means God have to already follow logic. So God cannot break mathematical rules, again there is no omnipotence. If you agree God's omnipotence and benovelnce, the problem of evil is very compelling. I don't think this is what Madhvacharya meant. That is why I am asking reference

Comment: @VARUN.NRAO That's clubbing of two different meanings in two different contexts. Purusha is actually just a "term" where it has 3 different meanings in 3 stages of realization. In this context, Apurushya means not man made are Vedas.

Comment: @AkshayS I am just curious, are you a advaithi, because you are talking about 3 stages. In Advaitha we take Vedas to be not created by Ishwara.

Comment: @AkshayS but LazyLubber said even according to Dvaitha Vedas were not created by God(Ishwara).

Comment: @AkshayS In dvaita, that is the meaning of apaurusheya. Vedas have no authors, not even God.

Comment: Vedas are themselves god.. because they existed before creation and after pralaya also.. when god says he can only be known from vedas meant BS shastraoynittvat OM ...he meant this only..

Comment: @prasanna R exactly my point.

Comment: you would be able to appreciate madhvas theory  of creation only when you understand what shankara said for what is the reason behind creation in his B.S. Shankara says that its playful sport.  it is playful sport then can you attribute saddist taught to good because he created so much suffering to jiva by his playful  creation? Ramanjuacharya why there is so much difference in creation by god.. for this he gives freewill to jiva athma during first creation so jiva started doing karma on its own and the God within them is dormant after that based on Karma the next time jiva born..

Comment: If free will was given during first creation why he had revoked suddenly during next creation its like breaking the law of creation which God created initialy.. This free will theory is absurd its not vedantic taught at all. And also is there no difference in jiva jada or whatever during first creation then there is no use in creation.. because everything is same, so Ramnuja theory fails badly.. For this Jiva have innate nature before creation that is like seed.. God is like Gardner who seed all the seed into the creation not be wasted

Comment: @PrasannaR but then what exactly is Madhwa's creation theory?

Comment: @PrasannaR what happens at the beginning according to Madhva's theory. I see there is a similar question here where you have commented https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34883/how-exactly-does-creation-happen-for-dwaithis

Comment: @PrasannaR But the answer is not clear. Jeeva and Jada were already present. Why did God create? There should be a reason right, what is the reason?

Comment: Jivas need to be expressed without that its laying waste.. Seed of tree.. you plant the seed it grows and express itself on its own nature.. what is there in the seed is innate nature of the seed not that of the gardner. gardner provides environment to grow.. you mean to say why garden in the first place the trees need to bear fruit.. fruit of moksha, they jivas need to climb up the ladded of moksha..